# aspx website is working in crome but not in firefox

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, server, publish

I have developed a website in **aspx c#**. Now, I **published** that website and host in **server**.

Now **problem** comes from here, that website is working perfect in **google crome** (after click on login button it redirect to another page) but the same thing is not working in **firefox**(not redirect just load the page).

Here is the staging site link **demo1aapp-001-site1.dtempurl.com/**

and here is the **creditial** of it

username : **Sanjay**
Password : **123**

Comment: Google `firefox xhr ns_binding_aborted`. It could be an addon blocking, it could just be that FF is more secure.

Comment: @wazz then how can I run in firefox?

Comment: I don't know...